# Python: A compact way to generate prime numbers in a given range

Tags: python, lambda, primes

Recently I read a very compact way to generate a list of prime numbers, in Python

```
#'prime' should be a pre-defined upper bound of the range
filter(lambda prime:all(prime%num for num in range(2,prime)),range(2,prime))
```

What are the `pros` and `cons` to adapt this to generate prime numbers? Is it Pythonic?

My personal idea is its's kinda readable and very simplified, I am not sure if it's a good way to code, and I am not positive that the code is efficient

Comment: You should post what you think are the pros and cons as well..

Comment: "Pythonic" is subjective, like "object-oriented" or "elegant".

Comment: This might be better suited for codereview.stackexchange.com

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13390924/generator-of-prime-numbers-in-python

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For `prime = 10000` that code performs 78021 divisions, while the traditional method requires no more than 2302.

http://ideone.com/X0MhGO

Your method can be improved by checking only odd numbers and stopping at `sqrt(x)`:

```
primes = [2] + filter(lambda p: all(p % n for n in range(3, int(sqrt(p)) + 1, 2)), range(3, max, 2))
```

This is still worse than the "traditional" algo, but much better than original one (2351 divs vs 78021).

Comment: is that possible to throw me a link to the traditional method that you are referring to? Cuz based on the code I read, even if we only consider odd numbers, there are ~5000 numbers, and we have to check the divider one by one till the square root of all numbers

Comment: @ChenXie: I added the link to ideone. The point is, you only need to check a number against _primes_ <= sqrt(x), not against _all_ numbers < x.

Answer (score 1):

The pros and cons are mostly algorithmic instead of syntactic. This code is using a naïve method to generate those primes, and while you could made some optimizations for it, it's better to use a [well established algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generating_primes) if you're running into performance problems. Otherwise, it doesn't really matter, though personally I would write the above code as a generator expression:

```
(cand for cand in range(2,upper_limit) if all(cand%num for num in range(2,cand)))
```

(Note: you have two unrelated variables both named `prime` in your original code, so I renamed them as I saw fit)

Comment: The OP's code is **not** using a sieve. It's using naive trial division.

Comment: @DanielFischer you're right! Now I see that I totally misread the code, and also that despite having an upper bound (common trait in the various sieves) it does not take advantage of it in any way, starting from scratch at each new candidate. Answer updated

Answer (score 0):

Cons: A generator would be a better choice.  I also find it to be rather slow.

Pros: It puts all the primes into a list, I guess that's a plus.

Here are the [functions](https://bitbucket.org/jgrigonis/projecteuler/src/3932138e20771594ab3cef4e94c443ef9af55d96/prime.py?at=default) I use around prime numbers.

Comment: Thanks for sharing the code, that is an enough good way to generate prime numbers. Per [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prime_number), it seems that only positive numbers can be prime numbers, just for your reference

Comment: I think I knew that, is there something in the code that says otherwise?

Answer (score 0):

There are better ways, this function is slow for these reasons:

- Goes through one by one, when you could simplify to two by two, since all even numbers except two are not prime
- Also, it loops all the way to the final number, when it will never have factors past it's square root

[This](http://www.daniweb.com/software-development/python/code/216880/check-if-a-number-is-a-prime-number-python) is an example of a better function to check if a number is prime.

If you are looking for speed at least, those are the main issues.

Comment: That's a better function, but it does a different thing.

Comment: @jgritty No it doesn't. They do the same thing...

Comment: the code i linked should replace `lambda prime:all(prime%num for num in range(2,prime))` in the given code